# jsp how to get base url cleanly without javascript

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I'm trying to get the base url (for example: https://stackoverflow.com/) without using javascript. But there seem to be a lot of ways to split it off from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask so I was wondering what the cleanest way was (or if there's a preferred method).

jstl functions would probably do the trick, but I'd like it to be as dynamically as possible, so I wouldn't have to change it if the /questions/ part was to change to let's say /question/.

```
${pageContext.request.scheme}://${pageContext.request.serverName}:${pageContext.request.serverPort}
```

Is an option, but it's well a bit verbose.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following with a little help of [JSTL](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) [functions](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html) taglib.

```
${fn:replace(pageContext.request.requestURL, pageContext.request.requestURI, '')}
```