# Get Root/Base Url In Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, base-url

What is the best way to get the root/base url of a web application in Spring MVC?

Base Url = http://www.example.com or http://www.example.com/VirtualDirectory

Comment: Where do you need this? In a controller or in a JSP page?

Comment: Everywhere within a website that has access to the contest/request/response to get it.

Comment: ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentServletMapping().toUriString()

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If base url is "http://www.example.com", then use the following to get the "*www.example.com*" part, without the "http://":

**From a Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someURL", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView doSomething(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException{
    //Try this:
    request.getLocalName(); 
    // or this
    request.getLocalAddr();
}
```

**From JSP:**

Declare this on top of your document:

```
<c:set var="baseURL" value="${pageContext.request.localName}"/> //or ".localAddr"
```

Then, to use it, reference the variable:

```
<a href="http://${baseURL}">Go Home</a>
```

Comment: or, from the JSP you can set the value of the "baseURL" variable dirrectly with the **"http://"** prefix

Comment: he method getLocalAddr() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest

Comment: Tbh you shouldn't use this as it's quite an old answer and is not up to date anymore. Have a look at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012525/get-root-base-url-in-spring-mvc/57800880#57800880

Answer (score 72):

I prefer to use

`final String baseUrl = 
ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().build().toUriString();`

It returns a completely built URL, scheme, server name and server port, rather than concatenating and replacing strings which is error prone.

Comment: I was looking for this one because this can be used everywhere, even at app startup.

Comment: It's what I was looking for!

Comment: It does not work:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current ServletRequestAttributes 

I'm using it in @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class) handler,   
 trying to use app base url for something, but it does not work.   
SpringBoot 2.1.7

Comment: Same here, I get that error anywhere but in the controller. I think it needs a request context to work.

Comment: This does not return the base URL. It instead returns the full request URL.

Answer (score 19):

### Explanation

I know this question is quite old but it's the only one I found about this topic, so I'd like to share my approach for future visitors.

If you want to get the base URL from a WebRequest you can do the following:

```
ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromRequestUri(HttpServletRequest request);
```

This will give you the scheme ("http" or "https"), host ("example.com"), port ("8080") and the path ("/some/path"), while `fromRequest(request)` would give you the query parameters as well. But as we want to get the base URL only (scheme, host, port) we don't need the query params.

Now you can just delete the path with the following line:

```
ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromRequestUri(HttpServletRequest request).replacePath(null);
```

---

### TLDR

Finally our one-liner to get the base URL would look like this:

```
//request URL: "http://example.com:8080/some/path?someParam=42"

String baseUrl = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromRequestUri(HttpServletRequest request)
        .replacePath(null)
        .build()
        .toUriString();

//baseUrl: "http://example.com:8080"
```

---

### Addition

If you want to use this outside a controller or somewhere, where you don't have the `HttpServletRequest` present, you can just replace

```
ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromRequestUri(HttpServletRequest request).replacePath(null)
```

with

```
ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
```

This will obtain the `HttpServletRequest` through spring's `RequestContextHolder`. You also won't need the `replacePath(null)` as it's already only the scheme, host and port.

Comment: Unfortunately, this works only in a bean or a controller. Searching for a solution to add the application server URL in generated PDFs for almost 2 days, no luck :(

Getting ``java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current ServletRequestAttributes`` outside the `controllers` and `beans`.

Comment: Be careful using this solution with the call `replacePath(null)` as it loses the application's root context (eg set via the `server.servlet.context-path` application property). The version that uses just `ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()` without the call to `replacePath(null)` automatically includes the app context root, so works as intended.

Answer (score 18):

You can also create your own method to get it:

```
public String getURLBase(HttpServletRequest request) throws MalformedURLException {

    URL requestURL = new URL(request.getRequestURL().toString());
    String port = requestURL.getPort() == -1 ? "" : ":" + requestURL.getPort();
    return requestURL.getProtocol() + "://" + requestURL.getHost() + port;

}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the URL is taken from the request. Meaning, if a certificate is signed for *.example.com, which resolves to 192.168.42.1 and the request was made with the IP address instead of the name, it will cause issues. The best way is to configure (hard code) the name somewhere in the application's configuration. This way, when sending things like emails, your emails will be more legit and trusted.

Answer (score 12):

Simply :

```java
/*
 * Returns the base URL from a request.
 *
 * @example: http://myhost:80/myapp
 * @example: https://mysecuredhost:443/
 */
String getBaseUrl(HttpServletRequest req) {
  return ""
    + req.getScheme() + "://"
    + req.getServerName()
    + ":" + req.getServerPort()
    + req.getContextPath();
}
```

Comment: Best answer in the world.

Comment: Really great answer

Answer (score 11):

request.getRequestURL().toString().replace(request.getRequestURI(), request.getContextPath())

Comment: Whats the difference between `getRequestURL` and `getRequestURI`?

Comment: take a look at this link https://coderanch.com/t/360343/java/request-getURL-request-getURI

Comment: Note: this doesn't work if you request URI is just "/" as it strips the slashes from the protocol.

Answer (score 9):

In controller, use `HttpServletRequest.getContextPath()`.

In JSP use Spring's tag library:  or jstl

Answer (score 8):

Either inject a `UriCompoenentsBuilder`:

```
@RequestMapping(yaddie yadda)
public void doit(UriComponentBuilder b) {
  //b is pre-populated with context URI here
}
```

. Or make it yourself (similar to Salims answer):

```
// Get full URL (http://user:pwd@www.example.com/root/some?k=v#hey)
URI requestUri = new URI(req.getRequestURL().toString());
// and strip last parts (http://user:pwd@www.example.com/root)
URI contextUri = new URI(requestUri.getScheme(), 
                         requestUri.getAuthority(), 
                         req.getContextPath(), 
                         null, 
                         null);
```

You can then use UriComponentsBuilder from that URI:

```
// http://user:pwd@www.example.com/root/some/other/14
URI complete = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(contextUri)
                                   .path("/some/other/{id}")
                                   .buildAndExpand(14)
                                   .toUri();
```

Comment: Thanks for the intro to `UriComponentBuilder` - I've never used it before. Very useful.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

In JSP

```
<c:set var="scheme" value="${pageContext.request.scheme}"/>
<c:set var="serverPort" value="${pageContext.request.serverPort}"/>
<c:set var="port" value=":${serverPort}"/>

<a href="${scheme}://${pageContext.request.serverName}${port}">base url</a>
```

reference https://github.com/spring-projects/greenhouse/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tags/urls/absoluteUrl.tag

Answer (score 1):

```
     @RequestMapping(value="/myMapping",method = RequestMethod.POST)
      public ModelandView myAction(HttpServletRequest request){

       //then follow this answer to get your Root url
     }
```

[Root URl of the servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629102/root-url-of-the-servlet/1629133#1629133)

If you need it in jsp then get in in controller and add it as object in ModelAndView.

Alternatively, if you need it in client side use javascript to retrieve it:
http://www.gotknowhow.com/articles/how-to-get-the-base-url-with-javascript

Comment: Personally, I would use this answer to get it in a JSP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278445/jsp-how-to-get-base-url-cleanly-without-javascript/4278830#4278830

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this question: [Finding your application's URL with only a ServletContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675730/finding-your-applications-url-with-only-a-servletcontext) shows why you should use relative url's instead, unless you have a very specific reason for wanting the root url.

Answer (score 0):

If you just interested in the host part of the url in the browser then directly from **request.getHeader("host"))** -

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@GetMapping("/host")
public String getHostName(HttpServletRequest request) {

     request.getLocalName() ; // it will return the hostname of the machine where server is running.

     request.getLocalName() ; // it will return the ip address of the machine where server is running.


    return request.getHeader("host"));

}
```

If the request url is `https://localhost:8082/host`

***localhost:8082***

Answer (score 0):

Here:

In your .jsp file inside the [body tag]

`<input type="hidden" id="baseurl" name="baseurl" value=" " />`

In your .js file

````
var baseUrl = windowurl.split('://')[1].split('/')[0]; //as to split function 
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url='http://'+baseUrl+'/your url in your controller';
xhr.open("POST", url); //using "POST" request coz that's what i was tryna do
xhr.send(); //object use to send```
````

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact requirement and reached to below solution:

```java
String baseUrl = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
                    .replacePath(null).replaceQuery(null).fragment(null).build().toUriString();
```

For this code to work, it should run inside a thread bound to a Servlet request.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

In the controller method, add a parameter of type HttpServletRequest. You can have this parameter and still have an @RequestBody parameter, which is what all the previous answers fail to mention.

```
@PostMapping ("/your_endpoint")
public ResponseEntity<Object> register(
   HttpServletRequest servletRequest,
   @RequestBody RegisterRequest request
) {

    String url = servletRequest.getRequestURL().toString();
    String contextPath = servletRequest.getRequestURI();
    String baseURL = url.replace(contextPath,"");

    /// .... Other code 

}
```

I tested this on Spring Boot 3.0.6.