# How to set absolute css path as in jsp

Tags: css, jsp, spring-mvc, absolute-path

Why we need absolute path and how I can set absolute path for css files which are included in my project.I am using spring mvc.The css files are in different folder which is inside web-inf folder in tomcat/webapp.Now i am using something like below

```
<link href="AllCSS/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

what should i need to do exactly?

Comment: When you say absolute path, what do you mean? And what folder are the CSS files in now?

Comment: @ZougenMoriver,i need something like this " https://test.co.uk/public " when I open view source ,it is possible to see the scripts being called from an external domain.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spring MVC, but this answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15718815/940252

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Root/Base Url In Spring MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012525/get-root-base-url-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: can any one tell me why we need to use absolute url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute in a webapp assumes starting from the webapp root context, in your case if */Allcss* is a directory under root, absolute would mean

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Allcss/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

if its a webapp context than

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: ..thanks for help..But this doesnt contain the "http://" part..am getting only "project/Allcss/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" do we need http part realy to make url as absolute ?

Comment: when you're linking to your local resources it doesn't have to contain http explicitly, when starting the app the above will be equivalent to e.g. *http:// localhost:8080/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css*. When you're reaching for an external resource than you'll need a full url. Also, for what concerns your question in the comment above if you linked your resources correctly it doesn't matter if you used absolute vs relative, http://jeffreybarke.net/2013/06/paths-and-urls-relative-and-absolute/ you should use what works for you better