# How to create a URL pointing to a REST endpoint in your system at runtime with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot to build a REST API. In my situation, there are 2 controllers: `ExportController` and `ImportController`. Please check the example code here:

#### Export Controller:

```java
@RestController
public class ExportController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/export", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> export(@RequestParam("id") String id) {
        // Processing...
    }

}
```

#### Import Controller:

```java
@RestController
public class ImportController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/import", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> importData(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // Processing...

       // What should I do here?
       String url = ...
    }

}
```

Inside my `ImportController`, I want to generate a URL pointing to the `/export` endpoint, e.g. `http://www.example.com/export?id=1234`.

I don't configure anything about the host or port in the `application.properties`. I want to get them at runtime.

Could you please show me how to achieve it? I searched a lot on the Internet but couldn't find the answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083170/how-to-configure-port-for-a-spring-boot-application

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012525/get-root-base-url-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can live with bringing [spring-hateoas](https://spring.io/projects/spring-hateoas) into your project then this will work:

```
import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.methodOn;

@RestController
public class ImportController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/import", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> importData(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String someId = "1234";

        ControllerLinkBuilder linkBuilder = ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo(methodOn(ExportController.class).export(someId));

        URI uri = linkBuilder.toUri();

        return ResponseEntity.ok(uri);
    }

}
```

This yields `http://localhost:8080/export?id=1234`

Comment: Interesting! I didn't know this. I will check it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `ServletUriComponentsBuilder` that comes with `Spring framework` since `3.1.RELEASE`.

Given that you have access to current request, You can do something like below.

```
 UriComponents uriComponents = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
        .fromRequest(httpServletRequest)
        .replacePath("/export")
        .queryParam("id",1234)
        .build();
 String url = uriComponents.toUri();
```

Comment: Hi, I don't want to hardcoded the string "/export" but to read it at runtime instead.

Comment: @TrietDoan, I see your point. But somewhere in your code there is going to be an `ImportController` with a `RequestMapping` annotation that has a hardcoded `path` value. You can always move these path values to a static String constant and use it everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RestController
public class ImportController {
    @PostMapping(value = "/import", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> importData(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // Processing...

       String url = request.getScheme() + "://" + 
            request.getServerName() + ":" +                           
            request.getServerPort() + "/export";
    }
}
```